# Singleton Pattern Usage

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

```
public Singleton setValue(String string, Object object) {
        values.put(string, object);
        return this;
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

EDITTED
This editted version is working well.

Comment: What do you think the error messages want to tell you?

Comment: You want to create a singleton and builder pattern?

Answer (score 1):

setValue could chain by returning the instance of the class after performing some assignment.

```java
    public Singleton setValue(String string, Object object) {
        // do some assignment
        return this;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method getInstance() is returning an Object type value.

You need to cast the object to:
`((Singleton) Singleton.getInstance()).setValue(...)`

If you want the class act like a builder, change the method to return a Singleton type object: `public static Singleton getInstance() {..}` and also in the setValue `public static Singleton setValue(..)`to be able to call multiple set as you wrote in the code.

Comment: yes that helped to stop that error but now i guess sth wrong here:                                
public static Singleton getInstance() {
  if (instance == null) {
   instance = new Singleton();
  }
  return instance.getInstance();
 }

Comment: cause it gives stackoverflowerror:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Singleton.getInstance()

Comment: Not sure about if the code is correct this way, maybe you should `return instance`  instead of `instance.getInstance()`

Comment: I have changed it like above. Now it gives neither error nor output.

Comment: You are not setting the values in the setValue method. `    public Singleton setValue(String string, Object object) {
        values.put(string, object);
        return this;
    }`